# How to make associations on this

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

[image: DATABASE CONNECTIVITY]

Hello, i'm new to rails. I have been fed up with active record associations. I did study associations from the rails guides. Yet i cant find myself a clear way to add associations to the models suggested in the diagram.

I have one doubt whether a single foreign key(SECOND MODEL) can reference two primary keys (SECOND MODEL LEVEL 2 FIRST & SECOND MODEL LEVEL 2 SECOND). This has been done because the user has to choose whether to add from the SECOND MODEL LEVEL 2 FIRST TABLE or the SECOND MODEL LEVEL 2 SECOND TABLE while inserting values into the SECOND MODEL.

If u find this hard to understand please leave a comment, ill make appropriate changes. And i would appreciate on how to query from the FINAL LEVEL FIRST with BASE-MODEL thorough a join condition.

Comment: I am pretty sure (not 100% though) MySQL does allow a field to be a foreign key to multiple tables; however, it is not an "or" reference; the field would require all referenced tables to have the value used for it. As far as I can remember, it is generally considered bad practice anyway; needing one suggests the model needs changed.

Comment: yea, i had a gut feeling it wouldn't work. Is there a way i could associate the FINAL MODEL to the BASE MODEL because i need it to implement search.

Comment: Otherwise how would i perform join.@Uueerdo

Comment: Many times, the solution can be simply having _"`b` and `c` reference `a`"_ instead of _"`a` reference `b` or `c`"_; though you won't be able to enforce _"no `a` is referenced by a `b` and a `c`"_.

Comment: i'm damn fed up with this prehistoric database. And rails conventions are very intimidating. Thanks man, ill figure out something.

Comment: As a note/disclaimer, I am not familiar with rails at all; just working from a strong RDBMS background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **polymorphic association** to refer to one table **OR** another, check the model below as per the posted image:

```
class BaseModel
    has_many :first_models
    has_many :second_models
end

class FirstModel
    belgons_to :base_model
    has_one :level_two_first_model
end

class LevelTwoFirstModel
    belgons_to :first_model
end


class SecondModel
    belgons_to :base_model
    has_many :final_first_levels, as: :referenceable, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :final_second_levels, as: :referenceable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class LevelOneSecondModel
    belongs_to :referenceable, polymorphic: true
    has_many :final_first_levels
end

class LevelTwoSecondModel
    belongs_to :referenceable, polymorphic: true
    has_many :final_first_levels
end


class FinalFirstLevel
     belongs_to :LevelOneSecondModel
end

class FinalSecondLevel
   belongs_to :LevelTwoSecondModel
end
```

**referenceable** is used as the glue between the parent table and other polymorphic associations *(LevelOneSecondModel **OR** LevelTwoSecondModel)*

**NB:**
Don't forget to add the below line in the migration files of the 2 children tables used in polymorphic association.

```
t.references :referenceable, polymorphic: true, index: true
```

**Reference:**
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: can i add the polymorphic association without modifying the table.@Shiko

Comment: No way, you have to change the table so Rails can understand where are the polymorphic associations. you can either add 2 fields in your migration file *(referenceable_id, referenceable_type)*  or add the line I showed you in my answer. I have used the polymorphic association a lot and really it is powerful.

Comment: Then i have a huge problem. Because i am working with a legacy database, they dont permit changes to it.

Comment: Btw should i add both (primary_key :field, foreign_key :field) in the model if i am using something else as primary key.

Comment: Because the primary_key name is different from the foreign_key name.

Comment: if you are working with legacy DB, what about you add the fields (referenceable_id:integer, referenceable_type:string) and define the association normally as in the example I showed you in the answer ?

Comment: i cant add those fields to the database, they strictly don't permit changes to the db.

Comment: if this is the way, then you can skip the polymorphic association and make a normal association where you refer to two models at the same time, but ofc not a nice solution. 
`has_many :final_first_levels`
`has_many :final_second_levels`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165689/discussion-between-shiko-and-gunder-gobi).